# Label rows and columns of a matrix in R Markdown with Latex and HTML rendering

Tags: html, latex, r-markdown, xaringan

I am having trouble rendering some Latex code with R Markdown in HTML using the excellent xaringan R package. Specifically I would like to label the rows and columns of a matrix as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters). The thing is that, as far as I understand, some Latex packages cannot be used in R Markdown. Therefore, I am using a `<div class="math">My matrix in Latex here</div>`. I'm almost there but I keep getting random opening single quotes that I cannot get rid of:

[image: opening single quotes in matrix]

Must be something silly. Any help would be much appreciated.

The Rmd code is as follows:

```
---
title: 'Matrix'
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader
---

<div class="math">
\[
\begin{array}{cc} &
\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{ccc}
p \\
q \\
r
\end{array}
&
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
.1 & .1 & 0 \\
.4 & 1 & 0 \\
.8 & 0 & .4
\end{array}
\right)
\end{array}
\]
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug of **xaringan**. A workaround is to move `\end{array}` to the end of the previous line, e.g.,

```
---
title: 'Matrix'
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader
---

<div class="math">
\[
\begin{array}{cc} &
\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{ccc}
p \\
q \\
r\end{array}
&
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
.1 & .1 & 0 \\
.4 & 1 & 0 \\
.8 & 0 & .4\end{array}
\right)\end{array}
\]
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wish I could vote this answer useful, but my reputation is too low for my vote to be displayed.

Comment: Don't worry. I don't really care. You may mark the answer as accepted if it works for you, or file a bug report to the Github repo `yihui/xaringan`. Thank you!